# how to arrange sequence png name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a solution that would help me do the following.

Suppose I have
so it will be arrange with 35_2_20 the last number 35_2_

```
list_ =[['35_2_20.png'],
        ['35_2_18.png'],
        ['35_2_9.png'],
        ['35_2_11.png'],
        ['35_2_7.png'],
        ['35_2_16.png'],
        ['35_2_6.png'],
        ['35_2_17.png'],
        ['35_2_1.png'],
        ['35_2_10.png'],
        ['35_2_19.png'],
        ['35_2_8.png'],
        ['35_2_4.png'],
        ['35_2_15.png'],
        ['35_2_3.png'],
        ['35_2_12.png'],
        ['35_2_2.png'],
        ['35_2_13.png'],
        ['35_2_5.png'],
        ['35_2_14.png']]
```

l'd like to rearrange it based upon an less to larg ordering. If there were a method to do  it would do the following

```
list_= [['35_2_20.png'],
    ['35_2_19.png'],
    ['35_2_18.png'],
    ['35_2_17.png'],
    ['35_2_16.png'],
    ['35_2_15.png'],
    ['35_2_14.png'],
    ['35_2_13.png'],
    ['35_2_12.png'],
    ['35_2_11.png'],
    ['35_2_10.png'],
    ['35_2_9.png'],
    ['35_2_8.png'],
    ['35_2_7.png'],
    ['35_2_6.png'],
    ['35_2_5.png'],
    ['35_2_4.png'],
    ['35_2_3.png'],
    ['35_2_2.png'],
    ['35_2_1.png']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install natsort:   [natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)

```
pip install natsort
```

then:

```
from natsort import natsorted
natsorted(list_)[::-1]

#OR

natsorted(list_,reverse=True)

#output
[['35_2_20.png'],
 ['35_2_19.png'],
 ['35_2_18.png'],
 ['35_2_17.png'],
 ['35_2_16.png'],
 ['35_2_15.png'],
 ['35_2_14.png'],
 ['35_2_13.png'],
 ['35_2_12.png'],
 ['35_2_11.png'],
 ['35_2_10.png'],
 ['35_2_9.png'],
 ['35_2_8.png'],
 ['35_2_7.png'],
 ['35_2_6.png'],
 ['35_2_5.png'],
 ['35_2_4.png'],
 ['35_2_3.png'],
 ['35_2_2.png'],
 ['35_2_1.png']]
```